# javascript drop downs hide/show table rows based on values

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning code, but have been tasked with creating a table, and when the user selects from multiple drop-down lists, whatever the user selected, is displayed in the table. (non-selected rows get hidden)

I want to place the code into a new html file and have it run. (my test is to cut and paste it into a txt doc, then change the name to html for testing) I can do this for other types of scripts, but for some reason, I cannot seem to get this one to run.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select.ddlFilterTableRow').bind('change', function () {
            $('select.ddlFilterTableRow').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
           $('#tableRegisterKids').find('.Row').hide();
            var critriaAttribute = '';

            $('select.ddlFilterTableRow').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() != '0') {
                    critriaAttribute += '[data-' + $(this).data('attribute') + '="' + $(this).val() + '"]';
                }
            });

            $('#tableRegisterKids').find('.Row' + critriaAttribute).show();
            $('#headerCount').html($('table#tableRegisterKids tr.Row:visible').length + ' Registered Kids');
            $('select.ddlFilterTableRow').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    });</script>



<select id="ddlAge" class="ddlFilterTableRow" data-attribute="age">
    <option value="0">Select All</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<select id="ddlSport" class="ddlFilterTableRow" data-attribute="sports">
    <option value="0">Select All</option>
    <option value="Foot Ball">Foot Ball</option>
    <option value="Chess">Chess</option>
    <option value="Cricket">Cricket</option>
    <option value="Bowling">Bowling</option>
</select>
<h1 id="headerCount"></h1>
<table id="tableRegisterKids">
    <tr>
        <th>Fullname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Sport</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Row" data-age="10" data-sports="Foot Ball">
        <td>Thulasi Ram.S</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Foot Ball</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Row" data-age="8" data-sports="Cricket">
        <td>Ram</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Cricket</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Row" data-age="6" data-sports="Chess">
        <td>Ram Kumar.S</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Chess</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Row" data-age="8" data-sports="Bowling">
        <td>Dinesh Kumar.S</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Bowling</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Row" data-age="6" data-sports="Bowling">
        <td>Raja Ram.S</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Bowling</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Row" data-age="10" data-sports="Chess">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you including jQuery when you copy and paste the code into your text file?? The code is running well here. http://jsfiddle.net/zLPMV/

You need to make sure you include jQuery into your page an easy test is to take it from google resources. Add this line of code to your text file above your script tag.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

P.S Did you write this code yourself or are you just using it as a resource and trying to get it to run?